# Service Fabric and Application Insights Performance Counters

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

Where can I find a list of performance counter names to be used with a Service Fabric cluster?  There is a list published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-generation-perf), but I would need the actual **exact names** to be used in the cluster's ARM template.  Currently I have the following configuration in the template :

```
"WadCfg": {
        "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
          "overallQuotaInMB": "1000",
          "sinks": "applicationInsights",
          "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {},
          "PerformanceCounters": {
            "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [
              {
                "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
                "sampleRate": "PT3M"
              },
              {
                "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Available MBytes",
                "sampleRate": "PT3M"
              }
            ]
          }
```

But only the "Memory\Available MBytes" actually shows up in Application Insights.

Answer (score 1):

Those counters are the actual windows performance counters. So you just need to look for them. Some examples:

http://techgenix.com/Key-Performance-Monitor-Counters/

http://www.appadmintools.com/documents/windows-performance-counters-explained/

Judging by all this information, the performance counters all follow the same pattern:

```
first column\second column
\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time
\\Memory\\Available MBytes
\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Received/sec
...
```

You might be able to find some more counters by running `typeperf` directly on the service fabric VM and capturing the output. You can also run it locally to get an idea of what is possible.

http://defaultreasoning.com/2009/06/25/list-all-performance-counters-on-a-windows-computer-and-export-it-to-a-file/

```
 C:>TypePerf.exe –q > counters.txt
```